# An adjective meaning something that is firmly held aloft

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been racking my brain and I can't seem to think of an adjective that means "firmly held aloft".  For example, a weathercock may be firmly held aloft at the top of a pole.  A sign may be firmly held aloft at the top of a scaffold.  A TV aerial may be firmly held aloft at the top of a house's ceiling.  I'd like a single adjective for this (for brevity), so I can say something like:

> I noticed the [firmly-held-aloft] weathercock on the church.
>   He pulled himself up by the [firmly-held-aloft] handlebars.
>   You could clearly see the time on the [firmly-held-aloft] clock.

I guess it's kind of the antonym of "dangling".  Can anyone think of any such adjectives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say the item was *[mounted](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mounted)* (meaning 5).

> To set in a raised position: mount a bed on blocks.

Answer (score 3):

Try using mounted, upheld, hoisted, bolstered, buttressed, or reinforced in an adjective clause.